# New data to array

Tags: vue.js

I would like to have three inputs which add data to each data array.

Input looks like this:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" v-model="newData">{{ newData }}
<button @click="addData(newData, 'first')">Add</button>
```

and script

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newData: 5,
    dimensions: [
    {
      title: 'first',
      data: [0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0]
    },
    {
      title: 'second',
      data: [1, 3, 8, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4, 6, 0]
    },
    {
      title: 'third',
      data: [6, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 10]
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    addData() {
      ???
    }
  }
})
```

What kind of should my addData method be? I can't push to particular dimension. I just manage to add new one.

I'm glad if anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `addData()` method to accept two parameters, the data and the dimension to which to push. Then it should look like the following:

```
addData(mData, mDimension) {
  this.dimensions.forEach((dimension) => {
    if (dimension['title'] === mDimension) {
      dimension['data'].push(parseInt(mData));
    }
  });
}
```

Don't forget to pass the data and dimension in your method call.

Comment: Thank you :)
How can i pass data and dimension in method call?

Comment: You'd pass them just like you would for any other method. So `@click="addData(newData, 'first')"`, for example.

Comment: I still get  _ReferenceError: dimensions is not defined_
from addData method

Comment: Great!

I'm sorry because i am so poor in js. 
I still get _not defined_ from title and data.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part naming both the param and iterator `dimension` and not using strings for the attribute names. I just tested the code and it works now.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
I think I have one last problem left:
If I change value of newData and then add it comes as a string. If i just press add button without changing value from deafault 5, it adds value correctly as a number.

Comment: Instead of pushing `mData`, push `parseInt(mData)`

Comment: Works! Thank you! :)